# space before a table ONLY IF the table is printed

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a report card for grades K-6 which prints certain tables based on the student's grade. For example, a 5th grader wouldn't have "Reading Stage" displayed on the report card, but a 1st grader would. I've got the styles formatted correctly to conditionally print the tables, but it's the spacing in between the tables I'm struggling with.

I want there to be a standard amount of space between tables, so I've tried things like adding a blank row as the first row of the table, or adding margin-top=50pt. Everything I've tried results in space added for ALL tables, even the hidden ones, so there is sometimes 200 points of dead space between tables. Not good.

I need a (creative) way to conditionally add space ONLY IF the table is going to be printed.

Comment: Can you share any code snippet or working fiddle for more clarifications? Thanks

Comment: Brilliant, Andy! I didn't even realize there was a negation option. That's exactly what I need! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm  unsure as to how you're hiding your `table`s. If you hide them via the `HTML5` `hidden` attribute or `display: none`, no top margin would interfere with your layout.

If for some reason you can't hide your content in one of these ways, [CSS negation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) could be helpful. In this example, I'm saying that all tables not of a certain `class` should have `margin-top: 1em`.

```css
table:not(.skip) {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.skip {
  position: relative;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.skip::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 150%;
  content: ' <-- no margin-top';
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>table</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="skip">
  <tr>
    <td>table</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>table</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="skip">
  <tr>
    <td>table</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>table</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the above has already answered but were you aware of @media print css? You could add some conditional print css that would only be applied when you are printing.

```js
// only for testing, you can print normally without this. It is just for stackoverflow testing...
$("#testPrint").on("click", function() {
  window.print();
});
```

```css
@media print {
  /* styles go here */
  .myTables {
    background: orange !important;
    margin: 100px !important;
    border: 1px solid black !important;
    width: 500px;
  }
}

.myTables {
  background: pink;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- you dont need this javascript either -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
  <table class='myTables'>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table class='myTables'>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table class='myTables'>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<button id="testPrint">TEST PRINT</button>
```